# Insert comma as separator while adding to list

Tags: list, groovy, xml-parsing, xmlnode

I have a xml as follows (test.xml):

```
<Test>
  <ClassId Value="11" Name="">
    <StudentName>John Doe</StudentName>
  </ClassId>
  <ClassId Value="15" Name="">
    <StudentName>Carl Lewis</StudentName>
    <StudentName>Usain Bolt</StudentName>
    <StudentName>Super User</StudentName>
  </ClassId>
  <ClassId Value="52" Name="">
    <StudentName>Marco Senna</StudentName>
    <StudentName>Luis Suarez</StudentName>
  </ClassId>
</Test>
```

I want to retrieve the  as a comma separated list. My code is as follows:

```
def list = []
def parser = new XmlSlurper().parse(test.xml)
parser.ClassId.each {
    list << it.StudentName
}
```

The list is as follows: 
**[John Doe, Carl LewisUsain BoltSuper User, Marco SennaLuis Suarez]** 
But instead of above I need the list as follows: 
**[John Doe, Carl Lewis, Usain Bolt, Super User, Marco Senna, Luis Suarez]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at a computer, but I believe:

```
parser.ClassId.StudentName*.text()
```

Should return the list you want

Comment: The list items are now successfully separated by comma, but the list structure doesn't seems right : [[.......]]
I am not able to compare this to another list : [....]

Comment: my apology: list.flatten() did the job. Thanks.